# django cms - The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server - postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-cms

Program versions:

```
django cms 3.0
python 3.4.2
django 1.7.3
```

Settings:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','localhost:8000',]
```

When using Sqlite, everything works fine.
With PostgreSQL, I get: `The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server.`
(With DEBUG - True, with either database, works fine.)

What am I doing wrong?

I forgot to mention that:

- I run django-cms on gunicorn and
- I use nGinx for static content

Comment: Have you created any pages? if not, you'll get a 404. If you have created and published a home page, post your urls.py file in dpaste.com or something and post a link to it

Comment: I haven't create any page initially.  After I did, I got: Bad Request (400).   This is my urls.py http://dpaste.com/228M8KC.  I can see my page in debug = false mode.   Behavior is the same with "runserver" or gunnicorn.

Comment: With ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',], works fine, but that's not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

So, after I did some research and debugging, this is how I have solved my problem:

In nGinx config , i had this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

when DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com','.example.com.',]
was not working because

get_host() was returning localhost:8000
and should return example.com

This fixed it:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```